# Prepending 'SU:' to Actor in Getstream-io Feed Update

Tags: getstream-io

Why do you have to prepending `SU:` to actor ID in a getstream-io feed update?

```
data = {'actor'  : 'SU:ronald',      
        'message': 'hello',          
        'object' : 'object',
        'verb'   : 'post'
        }
```

Without `SU:` I get the error: `The policy "Don't impersonate other users" (900) blocked this request`.

```
{'detail': 'The policy "Don\'t impersonate other users" (900) blocked this request, please consult the documentation https://getstream.io/docs/',
 'status_code': 403,
 'code': 17,
 'exception': 'NotAllowedException',
 'duration': '0.17ms'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I got from Stream.io support...

We are prefixing the userID within the Stream API with this.
`SU:` prefix means stream user reference such that when you call
enrich endpoints to read feeds, it will replace strings with referenced user object.
Actor colon rule is for prefixes, and simply ignore rule for regular exact string match.